# rsa_private_decrypt returns -1, error 0x0306B067

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, rsa

I want to test a RSA key pair using OpenSSL in C++. I encrypt a text and decrypt it immediately. The encryption is done successfully but the decryption return -1 always. The error number is:

```
0306B067:lib(3):func(107):reason(103)
```

I couldn't find out the reason... the code is:

```
char* text = "hello!!!";
unsigned char * cipher ;
unsigned char * decipher ;
int size = RSA_size(prvKey);
cipher = (unsigned char *)malloc(size);
decipher = (unsigned char *)malloc(size);
int cipherres = RSA_public_encrypt(size - 11/*strlen(text)*/,(unsigned char*)text,cipher,pubKey,RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);

int decipherres = RSA_private_decrypt(size,cipher,decipher,prvKey,RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);
if (decipherres == -1)
```

RSA key pair was generated befor using `RSA_generate_key_ex()` function and it's key pair are in pubKey and prvKey.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the look of this line:

> int cipherres = RSA_public_encrypt(size - 11/*strlen(text)*/,...

You should be using the length of text, which it seems you were doing previously. I don't know where you get the 11 from but magic numbers in code smell bad.

Try:

> int cipherres = RSA_public_encrypt(strlen(text),...

Also, referring to the documentation for RSA_public_encrypt [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RSA_public_encrypt.html), the following line looks wrong:

> int size = RSA_size(prvKey);

Are prvKey and pubKey the same size by definition? If not, try using the public key to get size before the encrypt:

> int size = RSA_size(pubKey);

You may then need to separately get the size of prvKey and malloc the decrypt buffer to that size.

Comment: first, thanks for your quick answer. i used strlen(txt) before but the result was the same. in the RSA_public_ecnrypt documentation as you linked, it says "flen must be less than RSA_size(rsa) - 11 for the PKCS #1 v1.5 based padding modes" and i use this size. i thought the RSA_size() returns muduluse size and there is no difference between public and private key, do you think i'm wrong?

Comment: I haven't used it myself but I found a similar question here with a useful answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426463/problem-with-openssl-library. It looks like you should be supplying the return value of the encrypt to the decrypt. This makes sense - it's telling the decrypt how many chars it should work on. The encrypt and decrypt buffers are a decent size, which is as it should be I'd think.

Comment: @Resource - I owe you an upvote but I'm out at the moment. Good catch on some of those.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your program. Some of them are pointed out by @Resource. Since you have this tagged as C++, here's the C++ way to do these things. Its the same basic program you wrote but with many of the kinks worked out.

The answer also uses [How to generate RSA private key using OpenSSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5927164/608639) for the RSA keypair generation.

OpenSSL recommends you use the EVP interfaces instead of `RSA_public_encrypt` and `RSA_private_decrypt`. Also see [EVP Asymmetric Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Asymmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption_of_an_Envelope) on the OpenSSL wiki.

```
#include <openssl/bn.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>

#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

#include <cassert>
#define ASSERT assert

using BN_ptr = std::unique_ptr<BIGNUM, decltype(&::BN_free)>;
using RSA_ptr = std::unique_ptr<RSA, decltype(&::RSA_free)>;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    ERR_load_crypto_strings();

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    RSA_ptr privKey(RSA_new(), ::RSA_free);
    RSA_ptr pubKey(RSA_new(), ::RSA_free);
    BN_ptr bn(BN_new(), ::BN_free);
    int rc;

    // Set exponent
    rc = BN_set_word(bn.get(), RSA_F4);
    ASSERT(rc == 1);
    if (rc != 1)
    {
        std::ostringstream msg;
        msg << "BN_set_word failed. Error 0x" << std::hex << ERR_get_error();
        throw std::runtime_error(msg.str());
    }

    // Generate private key
    rc = RSA_generate_key_ex(privKey.get(), 2048, bn.get(), NULL);
    ASSERT(rc == 1);
    if (rc != 1)
    {
        std::ostringstream msg;
        msg << "RSA_generate_key_ex failed. Error 0x" << std::hex << ERR_get_error();
        throw std::runtime_error(msg.str());
    }

    // Create a public key from private key
    pubKey.reset(RSAPublicKey_dup(privKey.get()));

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    std::string text = "Yoda said, Do or do not. There is no try.";
    std::string cipher, decipher;

    int size = RSA_size(privKey.get());
    ASSERT(size >= 0);
    if (size < 0)
    {
        std::ostringstream msg;
        msg << "RSA_size failed. Error 0x" << std::hex << ERR_get_error();
        throw std::runtime_error(msg.str());
    }

    // 41 due to RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING
    ASSERT(text.length() + 41 < size);
    if (text.length() + 41 >= size)
    {
        std::ostringstream msg;
        msg << "Plain text length is too long for modulus and padding";
        throw std::runtime_error(msg.str());
    }

    // Resize to maximum size
    cipher.resize(size);
    decipher.resize(size);

    rc = RSA_public_encrypt(text.length(),(unsigned char*)&text[0],
            (unsigned char*)&cipher[0], pubKey.get(), RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING);
    ASSERT(rc >= 0);
    if (rc < 0)
    {
        std::ostringstream msg;
        msg << "RSA_public_encrypt failed. Error 0x" << std::hex << ERR_get_error();
        throw std::runtime_error(msg.str());
    }

    // Resize now that we know the size
    cipher.resize(size);

    rc = RSA_private_decrypt(cipher.length(), (unsigned char*)&cipher[0],
            (unsigned char*)&decipher[0], privKey.get(), RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING);
    ASSERT(rc >= 0);
    if (rc < 0)
    {
        std::ostringstream msg;
        msg << "RSA_private_decrypt failed. Error 0x" << std::hex << ERR_get_error();
        throw std::runtime_error(msg.str());
    }

    std::cout << "Message: " << text << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Recovered: " << decipher << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program only needs the crypto portion of the library. The program was built from the OpenSSL 1.0.2 source directory with:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -DNDEBUG -I ./include test.cxx ./libcrypto.a -ldl -o test.exe
$ ./test.exe
Message: Yoda said, Do or do not. There is no try.
Recovered: Yoda said, Do or do not. There is no try.
```

---

Regarding this:

```
0306B067:lib(3):func(107):reason(103)
```

Try:

```
$ openssl errstr 0306B067
error:0306B067:bignum routines:BN_div:div by zero
```

My guess is, there is something wrong with `pubKey` or `privKey`.